# sed command to comment out text in file

Tags: bash, sed

Im trying to comment out lines within a file by a specific word. However there are multiple lines with a similar word.

```
BBB-m      more info
BBB        more info
BBB-a      more info
BBB-w      more info
```

Im looking to comment out the line with just 'BBB'
Is this possible? Thank you!

```
sed -i -- 's/BBB/; BBB/g' $file
```

Comment: Use `BBB$` to match the end of the line after the word.

Comment: That is not quite clear, do you mean a line containing a word `BBB` enclosed with whitespaces? `sed -E 's~^(.*\s)?BBB(\s|$)~// &~' file` ([demo](https://ideone.com/XvBtGk))?

Comment: unfortunately this actually didnt do anything for me... no changes within the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sh
awk '$1 == "BBB"{$0="; "$0}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
sed 's/^BBB[[:space:]]/; &/' file > tmp && mv tmp file
sed -E 's/^BBB([[:space:]]|$)/; &/' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

The `'$1 == "BBB"{$0="; "$0}1'` `awk` command means that if the first field value is equal to `BBB`, a `;`  is appended at the line start. Else, the line is output as is.

The `'s/^BBB[[:space:]]/; &/'` sed command matches a line that starts with `BBB` and any one whitespace and then is replaced with `;`, space and the matched text. The `-E` POSIX ERE variation with `^BBB([[:space:]]|$)` allows matching `BBB` as a standalone line.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/EB4Oxx):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='BBB-m      more info
BBB        more info
BBB-a      more info
BBB-w      more info'
awk '$1 == "BBB"{$0="; "$0}1' <<< "$s"
echo "---"
sed 's/^BBB[[:space:]]/; &/' <<< "$s"
```

Both return

```
BBB-m      more info
; BBB        more info
BBB-a      more info
BBB-w      more info
```

Comment: Thank you so much!   The following did the trick!!

`sed -i -- 's/^BBB[[:space:]]/; &/' $file`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
sed -i 's/^[^#]*BBB$/#&/' file
```

The **&** character matches the entire portion of the pattern and as @Barmar said in the comments the $ at the end of BBB filters out other lines.

Comment: this actually didnt do anything for me... no changes within the file unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/[[:punct:]]/!{s/BBB/; &/}' input_file
BBB-m      more info
; BBB        more info
BBB-a      more info
BBB-w      more info
```